# How to remove curved border around the outer svg path

Tags: svg, path

**The 4 Corners**

How to remove border radius around svg path.

I want it to be a plain rectangle, no curves.

I am trying to make the 4 curved areas smooth curves.

I am using this to do that, but I keep messing up

https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

```
M8930.86,6095.09c0,1523.93,9,3047.93-4.38,4571.74-5.45,620.4-298.7,1092-862.41,1374.07-180.83,90.48-374.86,136.11-582.76,135.54q-2247.4-6.12-4494.82-3c-491.81-.06-983.64-1.56-1475.44,1.55-558.1,3.53-975.64-248.06-1266.78-710.13-161-255.5-243.4-541.67-243.35-848.4.55-3019.42-4.28-6038.86,4-9058.26C6.68,903.92,376.89,342.15,991.59,107.9,1171.59,39.31,1361.09,0,1557.69.15c1941.87,1.37,3883.75-2.62,5825.6,2.77C8027.88,4.71,8584.42,354.73,8819,975.72c65,172.06,106.12,364.33,107.13,547.61C8934.47,3047.21,8930.86,4571.16,8930.86,6095.09ZM4474.19,5074.93C2965.08,5059.49,1690,6304.66,1698.93,7868.18c8.67,1523.83,1258.57,2799.5,2852.42,2759.35,1453.25-36.61,2693.51-1236.28,2693.74-2789.26C7245.32,6317.33,5996.39,5073.06,4474.19,5074.93ZM2932.53,2921.82c-3.47,827.66,686.25,1528.08,1493.15,1546.32C5281.11,4487.47,6002.93,3803.83,6013,2929c9.69-838.49-690.34-1541.14-1537.41-1546.16C3634,1377.88,2936.09,2073.87,2932.53,2921.82Z
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to make the 4 curved areas smooth curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the 4 values to draw the correct rectangle:
**left**(x), **right**(x) **top**(y), **bottom**(y).

First you need to make sure your commands are all absolute.
You can use the **"convert to absolute"** button.

Select the outermost commands (i.e left, right, top, bottom).

The last two values of a row represent the end coordinates of a path command (x, y).

[image: path editor]

In this case:

```
left: 5
top: 3
bottom: 12173   
right: 8927
```

The first sub path (describing the rounded rectangle) isreplaced by these commands:

```
M 5 3 (Moveto/starting point)
L 8927 3 (Lineto)
L 8927 12173 (Lineto)
L 5 12173 (Lineto)
z  (close path)
```

```css
svg {
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 8922 12170">
  <path d="
M 5 3  
L 8927 3
L 8927 12173
L 5 12173
z           
           
           M 4474.2 5074.9 C 2965.1 5059.5 1690 6304.7 1698.9 7868.2 C 1707.6 9392 2957.5 10667.7 4551.4 10627.5 C 6004.6 10590.9 7244.9 9391.3 7245.1 7838.3 C 7245.3 6317.3 5996.4 5073.1 4474.2 5074.9 Z 
           
           
           M 2932.5 2921.8 C 2929.1 3749.5 3618.8 4449.9 4425.7 4468.1 C 5281.1 4487.5 6002.9 3803.8 6013 2929 C 6022.7 2090.5 5322.7 1387.9 4475.6 1382.8 C 3634 1377.9 2936.1 2073.9 2932.5 2921.8 Z
           
           
           "></path>
</svg>
```

You can also use relative commands and apply rounding.

```
M 0 0  (rounded to zero)
h 8922 (horizontal line: width)
v 12170 (vertical line: height)
h -8922 (horizontal line: - width)
z
```

You can retrieve the width and height with `getBBox()` method.